# How to serve different thumbnails/images depending on users browser/platform

Tags: plugin-development, images, mobile

This is a general question to discuss approaches to filtering WordPress image sizes based on the browser/platform (such as a smart phone or netbook or desktop). The idea being that on a mobile we don't want to force people to download a 100kb image when a 20kb one would be big enough for their screen, thus saving them and yourself, bandwidth.

The outcome would be to make using CSS media queries a viable alternative to a separate theme for a mobile version of a site.

There are a few points to consider:

### User Interface

What would be the best way to allow a user to control the thumbnail and medium image sizes etc... for different platforms or indeed just for different screen sizes?

### Device Detection

What would the best way to detect the device/UA's screen capabilities on the server side. Are there any plugins that do this already?

### Implementation

How would you go about writing the code to create the different thumbnails, and then to alter WPs output according to the device / screen size? Ideally this would be theme agnostic so a call to `the_post_thumbnail('medium')` would return the appropriate size of image for the device/platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [tinysrc.net](http://tinysrc.net/), they do the hard work for you. I haven’t tested it, but it sounds promising.

Comment: Looks like a really handy service that. I'd still like to see if it could be done within wordpress itself though, rather than relying on a 3rd party. I'm not saying they would but they could start charging or rate limiting etc...